# How to make the xlabels vertical and reduce the size of the colorbar in heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I have the following code which produces my heatmap:

```
import seaborn as sns

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,40))
ax1 = sns.heatmap(df_trans, 
                  cmap="RdBu", 
                  annot=True, 
                  cbar_kws={'label': scor},
                  square=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap]

How do I make the xlabels (ie. the labels in the x-axis) from currently horizontal to being vertical?

Also as you can see the colorbar on the right is too large (too long) for my heatmap. How do I reduce the length of the colorbar?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)`

for the size of the colorbar I don't have an example to try but you can try adding in the `sns.seaborn` `cbar_kws={"shrink": 0.5}`

Comment: Thanks! With `cbar_kws`, having two arguments like this `cbar_kws={'label': scor, 'shrink': 0.5}` should still work right?

Comment: Yes, I think it should but i cannot try that in my code.